# Change webkit thumb css on webkit scrollbar hover

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar

Here is a self-explanatory jsfddle: https://jsfiddle.net/40Lo3agc/4/

I'd like to use CSS to change the appearance of the webkit scrollbar **thumb** when the webkit scrollbar is hovered. I **do not** want to do this by changing the hover state on the container which has the scrollbar.

I've been unable to find away to do this, and was hoping there is some way of selecting the thumb when the scrollbar is hovered. Something along the lines of:

```css
.container::-webkit-scrollbar:hover ~ .container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  /* some css */
}
```

Or perhaps

```css
.container::-webkit-scrollbar:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  /* some css */
}
```

These do not work.